# Why PyQt5 Qt class cannot access its own members?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

I have some problems working with PyQt5.QtCore Qt class. While creating .py file from .ui there are multiple errors connected with Qt class. Using Qt class in my main program also doesn't bring any results.

```
self.DateNum = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
self.DateNum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 280, 140, 30))
self.DateNum.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor))
self.DateNum.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ClickFocus)
self.DateNum.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
self.DateNum.setAcceptDrops(False)
```

While QtWidgets are working properly, all QtCore.Qt gives me an error like - "Cannot access member "ClickFocus" for type 'Type[Qt]' Member "ClickFocus" is unknown". Here is my import:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```

I tried different solutions from the internet, but nothing worked for me. From the error seems like Qt class is just empty... but its not.

Sorry if duplicated.

Comment: `QtCore.Qt.FocusPolicy.ClickFocus`

Comment: What Python and PyQt version are you using? The full namespace syntax is not required on PyQt5 (otherwise it would completely break compatibility) and it was just *introduced* in the latest versions before becoming mandatory for PyQt6. Besides, the error you're referring seems more like a bug.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9.9, PyQt5 5.15.4.

Comment: The messages you're seeing aren't Python/Qt errors: they're just junk spewed out by a buggy and/or poorly configured IDE. I'm guessing they're from some kind of type-hinting plugin (e.g. [pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance)) in VSCode or suchlike. If you run your code outside of an IDE, you won't see those messages.

Comment: @DaniilsDovgals For future reference, always consider the difference between *errors* and *warnings*, especially in an IDE. Except from actual syntax errors (ie. wrong indentation in Python) that depend on the language, anything else can only be a warning, because the IDE, as smart as it can be, cannot always know what will happen at execution (or compile) time. It's also always important to specify *when* you get errors or warnings: from your question it was *not* clear that you got those messages in the IDE. If you just ran the program, it would have worked anyway.

Comment: @DaniilsDovgals That said, remember that you should almost never care about the contents of files created by pyuic (except for learning purposes), since those files are intended to be **always** used as imported modules and **never** edited (which is a bad practice and almost always leads to unexpected errors or unwanted behavior). Please follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to understand how to properly use those files.

Comment: @musicamante Thanks a lot for your help and suggestions! However I must say, that even in newly created python file QtCore.Qt... throw errors like I already mentioned, and the code doesn't work. That is definitely an error, not a warning. Very interesting behavior from IDE, but I have what I have. I know that it is suggested not to edit files from pyuic, but that code simply didn't work on 100%. Anyways, Matt helped me with the solution and it might be helpful for someone. Still I appreciate your comments.

Comment: @DaniilsDovgals As said, in PyQt5 that namespace usage is not only not required, but, most importantly, it **must** work without it, as that is the standard behavior for PyQt5 (otherwise it would break **all** the PyQt5 programs written for previous PyQt5 versions). So, if the program does throw an actual error and does crash when run from a standard terminal/prompt, it's either a bug specific to the PyQt5 version, or an issue in your setup; otherwise if it only happens in the IDE, it's an issue with the IDE. In any case, the pyuic files **must** work without any modification at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Matt Clarke for moving me in right direction. So basically when .py file was created from .ui it created wrong code. I just added to all error places enum titles and everything worked. Looked for it here:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html

Now the same code looks like this:

```
self.DateNum = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
self.DateNum.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 280, 140, 30))
self.DateNum.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.CursorShape.IBeamCursor))
self.DateNum.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.FocusPolicy.ClickFocus)
self.DateNum.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ContextMenuPolicy.DefaultContextMenu)
self.DateNum.setAcceptDrops(False)
```

Comment: The code created from the ui file is correct. The issue is entirely caused by your IDE, which doesn't understand PyQt5 enums properly. The messages are just spurious warnings, not errors.